# How many security scoped bookmarks can be opened at once?

Tags: macos, cocoa, security

I have an application that I'd like to prepare for the Mac App Store.

The application needs to constantly access a number of "sources", be these volumes or folders, in order to be warned of any changes via FSEvents. The number of sources depends on the user.

To do this across relaunches I'll need to create and access each of them via a secutiry scoped bookmark. However, the documentation forewarns me of this problem:

"If you fail to relinquish your access to file-system resources when you no longer need them, your app leaks kernel resources. If sufficient kernel resources are leaked, your app loses its ability to add file-system locations to its sandbox, such as via Powerbox or security-scoped bookmarks, until relaunched."

Can somone tell me how many location I can actually have open at one time. I don't expect a user to need more than 30 or so sources at the very maximum, but I have no idea at what point I'm start having issues with having too many secutiry scoped bookmarks open at once.

Regards,

Tim

Comment: I cannot tell you a number, as I have no idea which kernel resources are used to make the bookmarks work, however I would be very surprised if 30 is anywhere near the limit.

Answer (score 0):

You will be fine with 30. In fact, you would probably be fine even with 1000. This has been confirmed by an Apple employee: https://devforums.apple.com/message/802537